# GraphQL - Nested Methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I am very new to GraphQL and wonder if I can type individual methods for type members

## Code

```
var express = require('express');
var graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql');

var { buildSchema } = require('graphql');

var schema = buildSchema(`
    type Query {
        beitraege: Beitrag
    }

    type Beitrag {
        beitr_name: String
        erst_name: String
    }
`);

var root = {

    // This is the part that does not work
    Beitrag: () => {

        beitr_name: () => {
            return "Foo";
        };

        erst_name: () =>  {
            return "Bar";
        }
    },

};

var app = express();

app.use("/graphql", graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    rootValue: root,
    graphiql: true,
}));

app.listen(3000, "0.0.0.0", () => {
    console.log("Started on port 3000");
});
```

This does not work as GraphQL seems do disallow to support individual methods for type-members. So I get `null` while testing this. My question is:

Is there a possibility to nest methods in such a way or do I have to return both strings every time I make a query?

Edit:

Tested in NodeJS GraphiQL

### Input Query

```
{
  beitraege {
    beitr_name
    erst_name
  }
}
```

### Output

```
{
  "data": {
    "beitraege": null
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say "does now work" do you mean "does not work"?

Comment: Also, could you put all the code so we can reproduce what you're seeing? Also, you haven't really spelled out what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my mistake:

instead of `Beitrag: () =>` it had to be `beitraege: () =>` as I do not want to define type members but schema members. I guess.

Comment: Strictly, `beitraege` is a field of type `Query`. GraphQL schemas don't really have members, just types. `Query` is a special type that needs to exist as the entry point. Non-scalar types (aka GraphQL "objects") have fields, each of which must have a type. Scalar types (eg `String`) don't have fields.